# Connecting Stylesheet in Wordpress using less styles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've compiled a static version of a custom theme using less and having trouble recognizing the main stylesheet. Framework bootstrap and whole stylesheet attempts to link to @import url("css/bootstrap.min.css"); I've tried adding the other css from the framework eg. @import url("css/bootstrap-theme.css");

Is there another layer of development to get this to work?

---

This is an enqueue issue. Having trouble getting correct syntax to enqueue scripts in multisite network. Syntax not working properly. Will post elsewhere.

Comment: Given that you are importing the stylesheet via the `@` CSS syntax, I don't see how it is an "enqueue issue"?

Comment: @s_ha_drum I got the static version to work using the compiled less files    `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">` <br>However now the issue is getting this all to work in WP w/jquery dependencies so it made sense to try enqueue. Still having trouble getting all this to work. I have specifics if you're up for looking at this with me.

Comment: What does jQuery (Javascript) have to do with CSS/stylesheets? And yes, if you have specifics, please post as much information as you have.

Comment: Since I wanted to try enqueuing styles and scripts (for bootstrap) it involved both... Here is the enqueue script http://pastebin.com/GbH00Pyt

 Here's my architecture for a bootstrap custom (not child) theme called 'jrmasonry' ->
 /jrmasonry/css/bootstrap.min.css (the compiled less file)
 /style.css is a duplicate of bootstrap.min.css

And dependencies -->
/jrmasonry/js/jquery.min.js, bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js
 (or just first is necessary)